# How to get haproxy to proxy TCP based on destination IP

Tags: docker, haproxy

I am working on getting a set of docker services available at a set of IP addresses and to make it resilient to failures. I have keepalived set up to manage the set of IP addresses on the nodes and am now trying to get haproxy to redirect TCP connections into those connections to docker services. I have one docker service for each externally-visible IP address.

Here is my haproxy.cfg:

```
global
    log 10.100.10.40:514 daemon

resolvers dns
    nameserver swarm 127.0.0.11:53
    hold valid 5s

listen test
    bind *:16000
    mode tcp
    log global
    option tcplog
    option logasap
    option log-health-checks
    timeout client 30s
    timeout server 30s
    timeout connect 5s
    balance leastconn
    default-server init-addr none

    acl IOS0 dst 10.94.10.210
    acl IOS1 dst 10.94.10.211
    acl IOS2 dst 10.94.10.212
    acl IOS3 dst 10.94.10.213

    use-server ios0 if IOS0 !IOS1 !IOS2 !IOS3
    use-server ios1 if IOS1 !IOS0 !IOS2 !IOS3
    use-server ios2 if IOS2 !IOS0 !IOS1 !IOS3
    use-server ios3 if IOS3 !IOS0 !IOS1 !IOS2

    server ios0 ios0-br:8000 resolvers dns check inter 5000
    server ios1 ios1-br:8000 resolvers dns check inter 5000
    server ios2 ios2-br:8000 resolvers dns check inter 5000
    server ios3 ios3-br:8000 resolvers dns check inter 5000
```

To test this I started things up with only one (of the 4 possible) docker services running. What I want to happen is that TCP connections to IP1 succeed while connections to IP2, IP3, IP4 all fail (until the corresponding docker services come up).

What I am seeing is that all the connections to all 4 IP addresses succeed and are directed to the one running service.

What must I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Are you running haproxy in a container or on the host with the vips?

Comment: Actually, this is probably a question for serverfault/unix

Comment: The short answer is setup a haproxy listener for each vip and configure one `server` per listener.  Also set `net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1` with `sysctl` so you can bind to the VIP when it's not there.

Comment: haproxy is in containers (one on each host that can handle the VIPs), not on the host directly. I am trying the ip_nonlocal_bind and will report back. Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty much working after Matt's suggestion... I had to change a few things. 1) Run haproxy in a docker container, not as a service, so I can use --privileged to allow using ip_nonlocal_bind. Since haproxy is not in the swarm any longer, I had to expose the end services' ports at different port numbers and refer to those in the proxy in haproxy.cfg.